# Find the determinent of a $4 \times 4$ matrix with the letter $a$ in it

Tags: matrices

Any idea how to compute the determinant of $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ when

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 8 & 1\\ 0 & 30 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 9 & a \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The $a$ in the $A_{44}$ location is really confusing me!

Comment: I've computed the value of the determinant using Matlab and it came out to 2-2*a.
I don't quite understand what you mean when you ask how to compute it. Certainly computing determinants of 3x3 matrices by hand is very tedious. I would imagine for 4x4 matrices to be doubly more so! Can't you use computer software to find the determinant?

Comment: @Malcolm Note that the determinant is much easier to compute when we expand down the fourth column.

Comment: I understand your problem concerning the symbol $a$. Usually, we use numbers in calculations. $a$ is just standing in for a number. Imagine $a=1234.56$ and you had to rewrite it every time you're writing the determinant of $A$. I don't know about you, but I'd rather write $a$ each time. At the end, if you wanted a numerical answer, you could replace $a$ with its value. The only thing you have to worry about $a$ is that it could be equal to 0. So don't divide by $a$ in your calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Just expand across the third row, as @Surb suggested:
\begin{equation}
|A| = -2 \left|
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 8 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 9 & a
\end{pmatrix} \right|
=-2 \left| 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & a 
\end{pmatrix} \right| = -2(a - 1) = 2 - 2a.
\end{equation}

Another option is to expand down the fourth column:

\begin{align}
| A| &=
-1 \left|\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 30 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 9 \end{pmatrix} \right| + a \left |
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 8 \\ 0 & 30 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right |.
\end{align}

The two determinants on the right simplify greatly by expanding down the first column:
\begin{equation}
\left|\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 30 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 9 \end{pmatrix} \right|
= 1\left| \begin{pmatrix} 30 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right| = -2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\left |
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 8 \\ 0 & 30 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right |
= 1 \left| \begin{pmatrix} 30 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right| = -2.
\end{equation}
So we see that $|A| = 2 - 2a$.

Comment: thanks so much! that makes perfect sense. then if was to try get the det of A^-1, do I do this via expansion also?

Comment: You can use the fact that $| A^{-1}| = 1/|A|$.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the determinant of A is a function of a.

Here is how to solve 4x4 matrix
https://www.sophia.org/tutorials/finding-the-determinant-of-a-4x4-matrix--5

but when you encounter a, you should keep it untouched. You can still use basic algebra to keep equations simple. For example, (3*a + 4) + (4*a + 5) = 7a+9 etc.

Here is Maple doing the calculation for you:

> > with(LinearAlgebra):
> >     M:=Matrix(4,[[1,4,8,1],[0,30,1,0],[0,2,0,0],[1,2,9,a]]);
> >     Determinant(M);
> >         -2 a + 2

What you actually need to calculate in general case of 4x4 matrices is:

```
M:=Matrix(4,[[a11,a12,a13,a14],[a21,a22,a23,a24],[a31,a32,a33,a34],[a41,a42,a43,a44]]);
Determinant(M);
```

which yields:

```
a11 a22 a33 a44 - a11 a22 a34 a43 - a11 a23 a32 a44 + a11 a23 a34 a42 + a11 a24 a32 a43 - a11 a24 a33 a42 - a12 a21 a33 a44 + a12 a21 a34 a43 + a12 a23 a31 a44 - a12 a23 a34 a41 - a12 a24 a31 a43 + a12 a24 a33 a41 + a13 a21 a32 a44 - a13 a21 a34 a42 - a13 a22 a31 a44 + a13 a22 a34 a41 + a13 a24 a31 a42 - a13 a24 a32 a41 - a14 a21 a32 a43 + a14 a21 a33 a42 + a14 a22 a31 a43 - a14 a22 a33 a41 - a14 a23 a31 a42 + a14 a23 a32 a41
```

here you can see this rule
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices
used.

Comment: +1 for actually addressing the OP's stated issue about $a$.